# Как устранить нетерпимость к чужому мнению на форуме?

Tags: обсуждение

**Чтобы создать здоровое общество и дружественную атмосферу, нужно как-то бороться с нетерпимостью к чужому мнению.**

Мнения, как известно, бывают разными. **Если вы полностью не согласны с предложенным ответом, то можете ответить сами,** участники проголосуют за тот ответ, который им покажется правильным.

Если вы сами не отвечаете, но хотели бы уточнить детали ответа, то можно это сделать в комментарии, **но вежливо и   доброжелательно.** Я считаю, что не следует использовать этот раздел для негативных, кратких и  субъективных по существу  оценок вида "это неправильно, непонятно,  неразумно, вот это перл! и т.д."

Вообще говоря, создается впечатление, что **в последнее время общая атмосфера на сайте изменилась к худшему, не следует этого допускать.**  Давайте не будем "троллить" друг друга, вешать ярлыки, ставить минусы за минусы, а не за ответ по существу. Не надо использовать "комментарии" так, будто вы учитель, ставящий оценки ученикам.

Также вежливо и доброжелательно нужно относиться к авторам вопросов, и уж тем более недопустимо говорить с ними  пренебрежительным тоном (а такое стало случаться).

**И предложение для обсуждения:**

1) О чем нужно писать в комментариях? Если вы даете свой, отличный от других ответ, имеет ли смысл  в комментарии критиковать эти другие ответы? Нужны ли вообще эти  **краткие комментарии-оценки без конструктивного содержания**?

2) **Нужна ли  специальная группа,** контролирующая поведение участников, куда можно будет обратиться с какими-то претензиями на эту тему. Если не принимать никаких мер, люди будут уходить с форума,  а постоянно отвечающих  здесь и так не  много.

Answer (score 2):

Вы безусловно правы, что вежливость — одно из главных условий использования нашего сайта. Любой пользователь, ведущий себя оскорбительно, нарушает правила, и к его учетной записи должны быть применены санкции.

Приведу цитату из статьи о комментировании из [Справки](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> #### Когда стоит оставлять комментарий?
>
> Комментарий нужно оставить, если вы хотите:
>
> - попросить автора уточнить вопрос;
> - представить
>     конструктивную критику, которая поможет автору улучшить
>     сообщение;
> - сделать уместное дополнение, содержащее не самую
>     распространенную информацию,  или, возможно, описание временного
>     явления (например, ссылку на соответствующий вопрос или предупреждение
>     автору о том, что вопрос был обновлен).
>
> #### Когда не следует оставлять комментарий?
>
> Не рекомендуется оставлять следующие комментарии.
>
> - **Предлагаемые правки**, *кардинально не
>     меняющих* смысл сообщения. Вместо этого внесите или предложите
>     правку.
> - **Ответ на вопрос**, или альтернатива
>     уже существующим ответам; вместо этого лучше отправьте полноценный
>     ответ (или внесите правки и дополнения в уже существующий).
> - **Комплименты**, не содержащие новой информации («+1,
>     великолепный ответ»); вместо этого, проголосуйте за данный ответ и поделитесь своей репутацией.
> - **Неконструктивная критика** («-1, особо
>     одаренным советую читать все комментарии»); вместо этого проголосуйте
>     против (и проголосуйте за более подходящий ответ или, если возможно,
>     добавьте свой).
> - **Вторая дискуссия** или
>     обсуждение противоположной точки зрения; для этого предлагаем
>     воспользоваться  чатом;
> - **Обсуждение
>     правил поведения в сообществе или политики сайта**; в подобных
>     случаях просим пользоваться Метой.

Если вы сталкиваетесь с несоблюдением этих рекомендаций, обязательно используйте *тревогу*, чтобы уведомить модераторов о нарушении правил.

По поводу вашего второго вопроса: вы всегда можете связаться с модераторами (мной и МаркИз), чтобы обсудить любые проблемы, связанные с сайтом. Просто дайте знать об этом (например, написав в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23242/) или упомянув о соответствующем желании где-нибудь в комментариях). После этого будет создан специальный чат, в котором, собственно, и будет происходить обсуждение.

Answer (score 0):

С Sybilla я в целом не согласен, ну что за обиды в самом деле? Неконкретно, непонятно и не актуально. В частности, мне не нравится постановка вопроса. При чем тут чужое или свое мнение? Уже отмечалось, здесь не дискуссионный клуб, а некий сервис вопросов и ответов.

Тем не менее, о наболевшем.

1. Правило о "второй дискуссии" непонятно и не работает. А где первая тогда?
2. Давайте четко пропишем, пусть не в правилах, пусть хоть как "моральный кодекс", примерный алгоритм на случай, если у автора видны очевидные "ляпы", но не очень понятно, реально ли это его позиция, или недоразумение.

В связи с этим предлагаю следующее.

3. Узаконить, что вопросы и комментарии, имеющие цель пояснить позицию отвечающего и исправить ответ (возможно по недоразумению искаженный) соответствуют формату ресурса.
4. Минусы, особенно прокомментированные, не считать чем-то оскорбительным и не ставить "в ответку".
5. Отвечать на комментарии строго по существу, ответы типа "следи за собой" и "читай Розенталя" удалять и карать при систематическом повторении подобного.

Насколько понимаю, всё это не противоречит правилам и в том или ином виде было высказано.

> Если вы даете свой, отличный от других ответ, имеет ли смысл в
>   комментарии критиковать эти другие ответы?

Обязательно. Этим ресурс и отличается от многих подобных, что есть инструмент обсуждения (пусть и недостаточный для предметной дискуссии).

> Нужны ли вообще эти краткие комментарии-оценки без конструктивного содержания?

Без конструктивного - не нужны. К сожалению, у всех разное понятие о конструктивности. Я к неконструктивным отношу комментарии, не имеющие целью прояснить позицию автора или исправить очевидную ошибку или нестыковку. Но это в принципе не такая уж и страшная вещь, комментирующий тоже может ошибаться. А вот некорректные по сути (троллинг) или форме (явная невежливость - см. ниже) надо пресекать жестко.

> Если вы полностью не согласны с предложенным ответом, то можете
>   ответить сами, участники проголосуют за тот ответ, который им
>   покажется правильным.

Это не работает совершенно. Число участников недостаточно для такой идеальной картинки.
Что касается самого пожелания, то несогласие с ответом не означает наличия альтернативного. Здесь не конкурс изобретателей Perpetuum Mobilе, чтобы выбирать лучший из двух или более заведомо неправильных ответов.

> Вы безусловно правы, что вежливость — одно из главных условий
>   использования нашего сайта

Вежливость без содержания - это флуд. Никто не против политеса, но не на пустом же месте?! Вы же даже в правилах прописали, что комментарии типа "спасибо" "пожалуйста" и "согласен" не приветствуются. Какая уж тут "вежливость" с точки зрения морализатора?

Вообще культура научного обсуждения несколько отличается от салонной. Не хочу далеко от темы уходить, но вот даже такое понятие как "переход на личности" трактуется совершенно по-разному. Аrgumentum ad hominem - это термин логики и риторики, прием осуждаемый в научном споре, но совсем не по причине его "невежливости", а только нелогичности.

Короче, вежливость - эта та "субстанция", моральная категория, которую невозможно "внедрить" указом, в каждом социуме о ней свои представления. Если уж без нее никак, нужно просто принять некую модель поведения объявить её образцом. Я такой среди участников не наблюдаю. Вот разве Людмила. Человек безусловно знающий и поэтому вполне толерантный к любым вопросам. Хотя и она иногда отвечает невпопад, что при некотором желании можно трактовать как невежливость.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60202/discussion-on-answer-by--------).